# Solr keep keyword query order

Tags: solr, lucene

I would like query to preserve keyword order.

**For example:**

`SCART 1` - I would like to match position 3, 4. Now `Solr` matches positions 2, 3, 4.

How to write query to meet those requirements? I would also like to specify slop distance. If this is not possible, I'm open for other suggestions.

**Index**

```
position |   1  2   3   4  5   6    7    8   9  
token    | HDMI 1 SCART 1 TV tuner yes DLNA yes
```

---

**Update:**

I will explain in details what I want. I want to use `Solr` for product attribute extraction. I will crawl web shop and put whole product page into `Solr`. On field I use some filters to strip unnecessary tokens (HTML, stop words).

**What I have tried so far:**

`SCART 1` - not okay, it just matches randomly in document

`"SCART 1"` - not okay, for upper example is working, but some pages have written it different - eg. `SCART input 1`

`"SCART 1"~5` - allmost okay, it matches "**SCART** input **1**", but if whole index looks like `HDMI input 1 SCART input 1` it matches following tokens "HDMI input **1** **SCART** input **1**"

**What I want:**

So I want to preserve keyword order even if I specify slop. If i query `"SCART 1"~5` I want that `1` matches after match of `SCART`, like this "HDMI input 1 **SCART** input **1**".

I don't know if this can be achieved with `Solr` and as I said I'm open for alternatives.

Comment: how about phrase query? keywords in quotes?

Comment: @sidgate Phrase query is (allmost) okay. Problem is that sometimes terms wont be adjacent, that's why I want to specify slop distance.

Comment: Okay... So, does [specifying slop](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Proximity_Searches) in your phrase query not do the job?

Comment: @femtoRgon I explained question more in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard query parser doesn't give quite the flexibility you will need to support this.  I don't believe that `edismax` handles this either.  As such, you will need to construct the query yourself, using SpanQueries:

```java
SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[2];
clauses[0] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "scart"));
clauses[1] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "1"));
Query query = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 5, true);
```

You can also use a different query parser, if you prefer.  The [SurroundQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser) handles these sorts of spans, something like:

```
5N(SCART, 1)
```